# Unexpected end-of-input error in Kibana POST request

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, cosine-similarity

I send the following POST request in Kibana. I got the following error. But the same request works in Postman client.

**Error:**

```
{

  "error" : {

    "root_cause" : [

      {

        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",

        "reason" : "[11:16269] [script] failed to parse field [params]"

      }

    ],

    "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",

    "reason" : "[11:16269] [script_score] failed to parse field [script]",

    "caused_by" : {

      "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",

      "reason" : "[11:16269] [script] failed to parse field [params]",

      "caused_by" : {

        "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",

        "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput); line: 10, column: 15])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput); line: 12, column: 1]"

      }

    }

  },

  "status" : 400

}
```

**Request:**

POST /sample_index/_search

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "doc['title_vector'].size() == 0 ? 0 :cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['title_vector']) + 1.0",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": [0.5398592948913574, -0.7566668391227722, 0.04461168125271797, -0.2684793174266815, -0.06062862277030945, 0.3980887830257416, 0.018403394147753716, -0.05054521933197975, -0.19672702252864838, -0.39494073390960693, 0.009594426490366459, 0.553227424621582, -0.11015673726797104, 0.33207616209983826, -0.20782124996185303, 0.610420286655426, -0.2354789823293686, -0.17941886186599731, -0.07044890522956848, -0.5445621609687805, -0.31410473585128784, -0.2941429913043976, 0.05097035691142082, -0.811872661113739, 0.32172778248786926, -0.20490604639053345, 0.40142858028411865, -0.2208421677350998, -0.04421447217464447, 0.5332352519035339, -0.24624258279800415, 0.4362853467464447, 0.7384172081947327, 0.18878786265850067, -0.7831365466117859, 0.0855928435921669, 0.030054695904254913, -0.3659694492816925, -0.14310625195503235, -0.30128052830696106, 0.3569716513156891, 0.5265516042709351, 0.7687430381774902, -0.25670990347862244, -0.12622840702533722, -0.476314902305603, -0.033769648522138596, 0.1860055923461914, -0.14743196964263916, -0.38942551612854004, -0.045895326882600784, -0.08003246039152145, 0.1845536231994629, -0.02998032420873642, -0.2701028287410736, -0.17774425446987152, -0.2808748781681061, 0.32470348477363586, -0.451164573431015, 0.049835432320833206, 0.2254597544670105, -0.01802029274404049, 0.3261609375476837, 0.40647268295288086, -0.09050709754228592, 0.10592185705900192, 0.1389138102531433, 0.5361014008522034, 0.21373336017131805, -0.2957477867603302, 0.40616345405578613, 0.5393425822257996, 0.36147597432136536, 0.13360203802585602, 0.3005269169807434, -0.16980338096618652, -0.004747828934341669, 0.10803189873695374, -0.16810442507266998, 0.6529152393341064, 0.0881659984588623, -0.3197547495365143, -0.3918364942073822, -0.19408196210861206, -0.16117356717586517, -0.6980555057525635, -0.19386504590511322, 0.06193597987294197, -0.4527856409549713, 0.05420546233654022, 0.7019262313842773, -0.009333805181086063, -0.21186037361621857, -0.3579225540161133, -0.020080767571926117, -0.21360771358013153, 0.13893605768680573, 0.23415756225585938, 0.46979689598083496, 0.11827527731657028, -0.12481388449668884, -0.3985167443752289, -0.18655610084533691, -0.33572980761528015, -0.37426242232322693, -0.4787536561489105, 0.0032884429674595594, -0.5355551242828369, 0.5293274521827698, 0.4929168224334717, 0.21401815116405487, -0.14704333245754242, 0.069062240421772, 0.07071194052696228, 0.817892849445343, -0.29767003655433655, -0.5415568947792053, 0.10125228017568588, -0.08599948137998581, -0.37749600410461426, 0.4672478139400482, 0.30601492524147034, 0.5614702105522156, -0.14358195662498474, -0.3536430597305298, -0.11226975172758102, 0.4586876630783081, -0.05565638840198517, 0.6529207825660706, -0.1733548790216446, -0.978161096572876, -0.003320892108604312, 0.13977061212062836, 0.2247927039861679, 0.026807742193341255, 0.20881472527980804, -0.12562598288059235, -0.4016979932785034, -1.1504006385803223, 0.19035457074642181, 0.3586266040802002, -0.26448801159858704, 0.22708095610141754, 0.3064292371273041, -0.12780530750751495, 0.27843421697616577, -0.09067044407129288, 0.45456287264823914, 0.45181432366371155, 0.27275899052619934, 0.6893038749694824, 0.0661335214972496, -0.1702771633863449, -0.15457339584827423, -0.04510529711842537, -0.22572998702526093, -0.08259648829698563, -0.2550409138202667, 0.3932051956653595, -0.13822247087955475, 0.5192695260047913, -0.5234261155128479, -0.20726336538791656, -0.14493218064308167, 0.3471468687057495, 0.17223359644412994, 0.11721622943878174, -0.14671266078948975, -0.07123339176177979, 0.25977441668510437, -0.3309487998485565, 0.14860275387763977, -0.6705752015113831, 0.67146235704422, -0.1242465153336525, -0.23834021389484406, 0.011681159026920795, 0.3742006719112396, 0.37842702865600586, 0.029343372210860252, 0.40634289383888245, -0.20983493328094482, 0.2086750864982605, -0.039437491446733475, 0.0070395455695688725, 0.30695807933807373, 0.042658496648073196, 0.3265968859195709, -0.13514657318592072, 0.19785308837890625, 0.04775746539235115, -0.2674489915370941, 0.4394092261791229, -0.1806897670030594, 0.1980883926153183, -0.002887468785047531, 0.16182580590248108, 0.0013114878674969077, -0.1195446327328682, 0.34813809394836426, -0.2281661182641983, -0.17540735006332397, 0.20401005446910858, 0.2976628243923187, -0.1828703135251999, 0.5016554594039917, 0.20406849682331085, 0.49341464042663574, 0.44383594393730164, -0.2157357931137085, -0.4448648989200592, -0.3427739441394806, 0.12979622185230255, 0.06941573321819305, 0.1071188822388649, 0.45327186584472656, -0.3079998791217804, 0.12487662583589554, 0.08746816962957382, -0.30003899335861206, -0.10184381157159805, -0.09104184061288834, -0.6718449592590332, 0.031522512435913086, 0.5609559416770935, -0.08246206492185593, -0.620427131652832, 0.009792105294764042, 0.01528495829552412, -0.33187994360923767, 0.948537290096283, 0.4623684585094452, 0.08302558213472366, -0.24096256494522095, -0.21363694965839386, -0.07284662127494812, -0.29296088218688965, -0.20479321479797363, 0.03528439998626709, -0.032271821051836014, 0.08422278612852097, -0.22629816830158234, -0.2915414571762085, 0.1192866861820221, -0.3722827136516571, 0.33558401465415955, 0.5897047519683838, 0.10792050510644913, -0.49181315302848816, -0.10575444251298904, 0.3417435884475708, -0.20328843593597412, -0.5360345244407654, 0.14714698493480682, 0.03285380080342293, 0.3574986159801483, -0.5504295229911804, -0.7865449786186218, 0.06021763011813164, 0.3283161222934723, 0.46576938033103943, -0.6513891816139221, 0.28619107604026794, -0.0012530082603916526, -0.4999563992023468, -0.4155079126358032, -0.4996558427810669, -0.08660131692886353, -0.09015730023384094, -0.2869439125061035, 0.14305071532726288, -0.27733099460601807, -0.20072118937969208, -0.10669303685426712, -0.014014046639204025, 0.44564804434776306, 0.07495786994695663, -0.01630399003624916, -0.18196748197078705, -0.19244278967380524, -0.1961759328842163, 0.41336050629615784, -0.5539005398750305, 0.4446620047092438, -0.6139371395111084, -0.0760912224650383, 0.47250989079475403, 0.13905490934848785, -0.15110404789447784, 0.2196819931268692, -0.015115287154912949, -0.0876191034913063, 0.2190818190574646, 0.15177731215953827, -0.11540143936872482, 0.3143292963504791, -0.7955248951911926, -0.14175251126289368, -0.2351459413766861, -0.0020031873136758804, 0.5531291961669922, 0.19006197154521942, -0.44695913791656494, 0.15765580534934998, -0.41821035742759705, -0.24712549149990082, -0.30841538310050964, 1.0628894567489624, 0.21696235239505768, -0.5680181384086609, 0.14360393583774567, 0.029083430767059326, 0.3504600524902344, -0.2073742300271988, -0.07237754017114639, -0.4631251394748688, -0.01993762142956257, 0.31713590025901794, 0.19752036035060883, -0.45867791771888733, 0.7844870090484619, -0.2899613082408905, -0.3508775234222412, 0.11184930056333542, 0.08467257022857666, 0.06063457950949669, 0.12691526114940643, -0.6400924324989319, 0.15319986641407013, 0.1950296014547348, -0.1831916719675064, -0.2643173336982727, -0.25775769352912903, -0.0383862741291523, 0.3277539312839508, 0.27097707986831665, -0.09319432824850082, 0.17078693211078644, -0.16352562606334686, 0.13986675441265106, -0.2126695066690445, -0.2646469473838806, 0.17556767165660858, 0.17156876623630524, 0.06933357566595078, 0.36875081062316895, -0.15373463928699493, -0.08859852701425552, -0.35353633761405945, -0.12193799763917923, -0.8119221329689026, -0.14899206161499023, 0.13862772285938263, 0.90940922498703, 0.5533017516136169, 0.46518024802207947, -0.16452465951442719, -0.08150187134742737, 0.06050856038928032, 0.004516924265772104, -0.07525651156902313, -0.36950698494911194, 0.13500910997390747, 0.5689918398857117, -0.13984568417072296, 0.13541090488433838, -0.1710337996482849, 0.5049394965171814, 0.31605851650238037, -0.11508357524871826, 0.25648927688598633, 0.22325031459331512, 0.0012158304452896118, 0.6063514351844788, -0.41860270500183105, -0.215798020362854, 0.0802639052271843, 0.3938862979412079, 0.41135427355766296, -0.3787707984447479, -0.08611714094877243, -0.08995003253221512, -0.14258436858654022, -0.328289270401001, -0.15199796855449677, 0.291996568441391, 0.3480320870876312, -0.12029280513525009, -0.29980534315109253, -0.15381667017936707, 0.01715751923620701, 0.418067067861557, 0.10767596960067749, -0.49369239807128906, -0.24448750913143158, -0.1285122185945511, 0.1464521884918213, 0.06308989971876144, 0.27997395396232605, -0.07993294298648834, -0.3860047161579132, 0.26958078145980835, -0.041770875453948975, 1.2096740007400513, -0.3259912431240082, 0.03931817784905434, -0.03341643512248993, -0.4666934907436371, -0.015846841037273407, -0.5081338882446289, 0.0096580283716321, 0.02544138766825199, -0.09315574169158936, 0.1747598499059677, 0.36882948875427246, -0.06870802491903305, 0.6053507328033447, -0.2759757936000824, 0.15961496531963348, 0.8063604235649109, -0.15020887553691864, -0.15171681344509125, -0.060200419276952744, -0.4110613167285919, -0.5835322737693787, -0.09726080298423767, -0.2392592579126358, -0.3616079092025757, 0.027558647096157074, 0.05291641876101494, 0.12349791079759598, -0.007836289703845978, 0.39525559544563293, -0.007334516849368811, 0.2399410605430603, -0.4273543357849121, 0.0991259291768074, -0.4819057881832123, 0.3256849944591522, 0.3032423257827759, -0.36083295941352844, -0.07435029000043869, 0.2121112197637558, -0.364762544631958, -0.1596834510564804, 0.04949704930186272, -0.16109593212604523, 0.5034934878349304, 0.10951238125562668, 0.2869861423969269, 0.13778208196163177, 0.07069063931703568, -0.09771542996168137, -0.44196006655693054, 0.5653741955757141, 0.05989822372794151, -0.04989922046661377, -0.014927036128938198, -0.02302585542201996, 0.17904798686504364, -0.002676159143447876, 0.3416226804256439, -0.3578616678714752, -0.2932840585708618, 0.2818126976490021, 0.019605768844485283, -0.37913379073143005, -0.17880195379257202, -0.44554567337036133, -0.4738466441631317, 0.28100961446762085, -0.1904536932706833, -0.03373843804001808, -0.2823610007762909, -0.19747000932693481, 0.2464223951101303, 0.22571444511413574, -0.05425698682665825, -0.16406866908073425, 0.3493328392505646, -0.019189564511179924, 0.1714441031217575, 0.05705219507217407, 0.5947189927101135, 0.4346608817577362, 0.676112711429596, -0.5242040753364563, 0.3332209587097168, 0.25352028012275696, 0.027646541595458984, 0.36309531331062317, -0.191823348402977, -0.011616709642112255, 0.2157600373029709, 0.34172940254211426, 0.3011607527732849, -0.09793389588594437, -0.21880114078521729, 0.5951963067054749, 0.2308332920074463, -0.13228900730609894, -0.6290040612220764, -0.08339443057775497, 0.1325439065694809, -0.6515927314758301, 0.20590782165527344, -0.8780518174171448, -0.7029945254325867, 0.13595467805862427, 0.1822308450937271, -0.2715843915939331, -0.3809267580509186, -0.15282316505908966, 0.22329704463481903, -0.22305679321289062, -0.012069642543792725, 0.2796964943408966, -0.09808734059333801, 0.20639513432979584, -0.07919856160879135, -0.2864263653755188, -0.14806243777275085, -0.045156244188547134, 0.5580117106437683, 0.22284358739852905, -0.5415909886360168, -0.21465997397899628, 0.11937487125396729, -0.20431263744831085, -0.2403395175933838, 0.07580457627773285, 0.14617057144641876, -0.13944444060325623, 0.24228675663471222, 0.4678296148777008, -0.031120838597416878, -0.12779338657855988, 0.08634798973798752, -0.04670761153101921, 0.06502512842416763, 0.07903987914323807, 0.3355945348739624, -0.06577946990728378, 0.07166757434606552, -0.1437894105911255, -0.5630078911781311, -0.13233913481235504, 0.01655399054288864, 0.3199481964111328, 0.14370183646678925, 0.11952924728393555, 0.5970006585121155, -0.07086852192878723, 0.10095593333244324, -0.7246183753013611, 0.6260027289390564, -0.4862600564956665, -18.213258743286133, 0.38144493103027344, 0.08877747505903244, 0.3688160479068756, 0.20332185924053192, -0.4959397614002228, 0.4932158887386322, -0.2113923579454422, -0.1950404793024063, 0.3772925138473511, 0.3376901149749756, 0.028192894533276558, -0.597175657749176, 0.10751038044691086, -0.38332363963127136, 0.061080824583768845, 0.2934887707233429, -0.16140936315059662, -0.030300596728920937, -0.11393174529075623, -0.4879361093044281, -0.08312537521123886, 0.5829288363456726, -0.017795657739043236, 0.17447303235530853, 0.19649899005889893, 0.26811954379081726, -0.18477855622768402, 0.026489676907658577, -0.08490554243326187, 0.04047516733407974, -0.05758599564433098, 0.1733301877975464, 0.30296510457992554, 0.12135863304138184, -0.5401827692985535, 0.01981624960899353, 0.10279199481010437, 0.5150095820426941, -0.21353882551193237, 0.536064624786377, 0.3912695348262787, 0.6470407843589783, -0.14603863656520844, -0.17455945909023285, 0.26098909974098206, -0.46810880303382874, -0.4509357213973999, 0.6088793873786926, -0.09780841320753098, 0.24819111824035645, 0.2163211554288864, -0.3753402531147003, 0.6355602741241455, -0.3911609649658203, -0.05401340499520302, -0.16659629344940186, -0.13565801084041595, 0.501842200756073, 0.1643461138010025, -0.21625493466854095, -0.6514524221420288, 0.8899388313293457, 0.26289352774620056, -0.25896701216697693, -0.3272574245929718, 0.15999677777290344, -0.26547718048095703, -0.3032608926296234, -0.25007131695747375, -0.03964695334434509, 0.1334560066461563, -0.17761678993701935, -0.004811423365026712, -0.08859457820653915, -0.13191309571266174, -0.4322088062763214, -0.6202206015586853, -0.14941012859344482, 0.5533108711242676, -0.9611896872520447, 0.14862070977687836, 0.358111172914505, -0.2760471999645233, -0.15035228431224823, 0.5983766913414001, -0.09283676743507385, 0.40859857201576233, 0.03840084746479988, -0.0427594929933548, 0.23755036294460297, 0.552716076374054, 0.25461438298225403, 0.08937105536460876, 0.5074090361595154, -0.016884038224816322, -0.2121085524559021, 0.21483175456523895, -0.3174271285533905, -0.5140398144721985, 0.06363151222467422, 0.014451566152274609, -0.4032210409641266, -0.0754266306757927, -0.2747887670993805, -0.05837796628475189, 0.7825634479522705, 0.4075222909450531, -0.7825568318367004, -0.35135790705680847, 0.2962072193622589, -0.2863955795764923, -0.13005737960338593, 0.7307493686676025, 0.3552493751049042, -0.19790320098400116, -0.8183410167694092, -0.17674492299556732, 0.24666698276996613, -0.01461823284626007, 0.2410256713628769, -0.17540700733661652, 0.18241678178310394, 0.08976519852876663, -0.08760727196931839, 0.012153185904026031, -0.2104892134666443, -0.7453539371490479, -0.06952495127916336, -0.28295353055000305, 0.6779361367225647, -0.5319180488586426, -0.19127275049686432, -0.07256310433149338, 0.2968808710575104, 0.2115486115217209, 0.26703646779060364, 0.385223388671875, 0.31249818205833435, -0.11475372314453125, -0.12362142652273178, -0.025776103138923645, 0.19199372828006744, -0.27560412883758545, -0.027614548802375793, 0.17952845990657806, 0.30890682339668274, -0.4669407308101654, -1.1229356527328491, -0.14094625413417816, -0.7237748503684998, -0.33700716495513916, -0.29603925347328186, -0.20345592498779297, 0.11142813414335251, 0.08747435361146927, 0.14150665700435638, -0.7253284454345703, 0.22486639022827148, 0.4361128509044647, 0.22853289544582367, 0.08715341240167618, 0.2346210479736328, -0.03457959368824959, -0.17921000719070435, -0.6874427199363708, 0.16873355209827423, -0.18384100496768951, 0.23986661434173584, 0.28883546590805054, 0.13879145681858063, -0.15344975888729095, 0.316563218832016, -0.25333499908447266, 0.1651841402053833, -0.18934951722621918, -0.004195801913738251, 0.041273608803749084, -0.14218632876873016, -0.01217249408364296, 0.23939736187458038, -0.3173660933971405, -0.4909832775592804, -0.4912407696247101, 0.08538653701543808, -0.28222790360450745, -0.15587706863880157, 0.10141023248434067, 0.3789379894733429, -0.11405836790800095, 0.751940906047821, 0.3117077648639679, -0.1643051952123642, -0.34755292534828186, -0.11532503366470337, 0.2710844576358795, 0.5446938872337341, -0.6947710514068604, 0.32719090580940247, -0.26343023777008057, 0.42235779762268066, 0.5053179264068604, 0.5381287336349487, -0.06117519736289978, 0.21823382377624512, -0.2707849144935608, 0.2575806677341461, 0.3865841329097748, -0.314393013715744, 0.34935781359672546, 0.12102178484201431]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_source": {
        "includes": ["title"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Kibana bug -- when you investigate w/ Chrome Devtools you'll see that the proxied request's payload is terminated sooner than it should be. Try prettifying the payload like so and it should work:

```json
{
  "size":100,
  "query":{
    "script_score":{
      "query":{
        "match_all":{

        }
      },
      "script":{
        "source":"doc['title_vector'].size() == 0 ? 0 :cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['title_vector']) + 1.0",
        "params":{
          "query_vector":[
            0.5398592948913574,
            -0.7566668391227722,
            0.04461168125271797,
            -0.2684793174266815,
            -0.06062862277030945,
            0.3980887830257416,
            0.018403394147753716,
            -0.05054521933197975,
            -0.19672702252864838,
            -0.39494073390960693,
            0.009594426490366459,
            0.553227424621582,
            -0.11015673726797104,
            0.33207616209983826,
            -0.20782124996185303,
            0.610420286655426,
            -0.2354789823293686,
            -0.17941886186599731,
            -0.07044890522956848,
            -0.5445621609687805,
            -0.31410473585128784,
            -0.2941429913043976,
            0.05097035691142082,
            -0.811872661113739,
            0.32172778248786926,
            -0.20490604639053345,
            0.40142858028411865,
            -0.2208421677350998,
            -0.04421447217464447,
            0.5332352519035339,
            -0.24624258279800415,
            0.4362853467464447,
            0.7384172081947327,
            0.18878786265850067,
            -0.7831365466117859,
            0.0855928435921669,
            0.030054695904254913,
            -0.3659694492816925,
            -0.14310625195503235,
            -0.30128052830696106,
            0.3569716513156891,
            0.5265516042709351,
            0.7687430381774902,
            -0.25670990347862244,
            -0.12622840702533722,
            -0.476314902305603,
            -0.033769648522138596,
            0.1860055923461914,
            -0.14743196964263916,
            -0.38942551612854004,
            -0.045895326882600784,
            -0.08003246039152145,
            0.1845536231994629,
            -0.02998032420873642,
            -0.2701028287410736,
            -0.17774425446987152,
            -0.2808748781681061,
            0.32470348477363586,
            -0.451164573431015,
            0.049835432320833206,
            0.2254597544670105,
            -0.01802029274404049,
            0.3261609375476837,
            0.40647268295288086,
            -0.09050709754228592,
            0.10592185705900192,
            0.1389138102531433,
            0.5361014008522034,
            0.21373336017131805,
            -0.2957477867603302,
            0.40616345405578613,
            0.5393425822257996,
            0.36147597432136536,
            0.13360203802585602,
            0.3005269169807434,
            -0.16980338096618652,
            -0.004747828934341669,
            0.10803189873695374,
            -0.16810442507266998,
            0.6529152393341064,
            0.0881659984588623,
            -0.3197547495365143,
            -0.3918364942073822,
            -0.19408196210861206,
            -0.16117356717586517,
            -0.6980555057525635,
            -0.19386504590511322,
            0.06193597987294197,
            -0.4527856409549713,
            0.05420546233654022,
            0.7019262313842773,
            -0.009333805181086063,
            -0.21186037361621857,
            -0.3579225540161133,
            -0.020080767571926117,
            -0.21360771358013153,
            0.13893605768680573,
            0.23415756225585938,
            0.46979689598083496,
            0.11827527731657028,
            -0.12481388449668884,
            -0.3985167443752289,
            -0.18655610084533691,
            -0.33572980761528015,
            -0.37426242232322693,
            -0.4787536561489105,
            0.0032884429674595594,
            -0.5355551242828369,
            0.5293274521827698,
            0.4929168224334717,
            0.21401815116405487,
            -0.14704333245754242,
            0.069062240421772,
            0.07071194052696228,
            0.817892849445343,
            -0.29767003655433655,
            -0.5415568947792053,
            0.10125228017568588,
            -0.08599948137998581,
            -0.37749600410461426,
            0.4672478139400482,
            0.30601492524147034,
            0.5614702105522156,
            -0.14358195662498474,
            -0.3536430597305298,
            -0.11226975172758102,
            0.4586876630783081,
            -0.05565638840198517,
            0.6529207825660706,
            -0.1733548790216446,
            -0.978161096572876,
            -0.003320892108604312,
            0.13977061212062836,
            0.2247927039861679,
            0.026807742193341255,
            0.20881472527980804,
            -0.12562598288059235,
            -0.4016979932785034,
            -1.1504006385803223,
            0.19035457074642181,
            0.3586266040802002,
            -0.26448801159858704,
            0.22708095610141754,
            0.3064292371273041,
            -0.12780530750751495,
            0.27843421697616577,
            -0.09067044407129288,
            0.45456287264823914,
            0.45181432366371155,
            0.27275899052619934,
            0.6893038749694824,
            0.0661335214972496,
            -0.1702771633863449,
            -0.15457339584827423,
            -0.04510529711842537,
            -0.22572998702526093,
            -0.08259648829698563,
            -0.2550409138202667,
            0.3932051956653595,
            -0.13822247087955475,
            0.5192695260047913,
            -0.5234261155128479,
            -0.20726336538791656,
            -0.14493218064308167,
            0.3471468687057495,
            0.17223359644412994,
            0.11721622943878174,
            -0.14671266078948975,
            -0.07123339176177979,
            0.25977441668510437,
            -0.3309487998485565,
            0.14860275387763977,
            -0.6705752015113831,
            0.67146235704422,
            -0.1242465153336525,
            -0.23834021389484406,
            0.011681159026920795,
            0.3742006719112396,
            0.37842702865600586,
            0.029343372210860252,
            0.40634289383888245,
            -0.20983493328094482,
            0.2086750864982605,
            -0.039437491446733475,
            0.0070395455695688725,
            0.30695807933807373,
            0.042658496648073196,
            0.3265968859195709,
            -0.13514657318592072,
            0.19785308837890625,
            0.04775746539235115,
            -0.2674489915370941,
            0.4394092261791229,
            -0.1806897670030594,
            0.1980883926153183,
            -0.002887468785047531,
            0.16182580590248108,
            0.0013114878674969077,
            -0.1195446327328682,
            0.34813809394836426,
            -0.2281661182641983,
            -0.17540735006332397,
            0.20401005446910858,
            0.2976628243923187,
            -0.1828703135251999,
            0.5016554594039917,
            0.20406849682331085,
            0.49341464042663574,
            0.44383594393730164,
            -0.2157357931137085,
            -0.4448648989200592,
            -0.3427739441394806,
            0.12979622185230255,
            0.06941573321819305,
            0.1071188822388649,
            0.45327186584472656,
            -0.3079998791217804,
            0.12487662583589554,
            0.08746816962957382,
            -0.30003899335861206,
            -0.10184381157159805,
            -0.09104184061288834,
            -0.6718449592590332,
            0.031522512435913086,
            0.5609559416770935,
            -0.08246206492185593,
            -0.620427131652832,
            0.009792105294764042,
            0.01528495829552412,
            -0.33187994360923767,
            0.948537290096283,
            0.4623684585094452,
            0.08302558213472366,
            -0.24096256494522095,
            -0.21363694965839386,
            -0.07284662127494812,
            -0.29296088218688965,
            -0.20479321479797363,
            0.03528439998626709,
            -0.032271821051836014,
            0.08422278612852097,
            -0.22629816830158234,
            -0.2915414571762085,
            0.1192866861820221,
            -0.3722827136516571,
            0.33558401465415955,
            0.5897047519683838,
            0.10792050510644913,
            -0.49181315302848816,
            -0.10575444251298904,
            0.3417435884475708,
            -0.20328843593597412,
            -0.5360345244407654,
            0.14714698493480682,
            0.03285380080342293,
            0.3574986159801483,
            -0.5504295229911804,
            -0.7865449786186218,
            0.06021763011813164,
            0.3283161222934723,
            0.46576938033103943,
            -0.6513891816139221,
            0.28619107604026794,
            -0.0012530082603916526,
            -0.4999563992023468,
            -0.4155079126358032,
            -0.4996558427810669,
            -0.08660131692886353,
            -0.09015730023384094,
            -0.2869439125061035,
            0.14305071532726288,
            -0.27733099460601807,
            -0.20072118937969208,
            -0.10669303685426712,
            -0.014014046639204025,
            0.44564804434776306,
            0.07495786994695663,
            -0.01630399003624916,
            -0.18196748197078705,
            -0.19244278967380524,
            -0.1961759328842163,
            0.41336050629615784,
            -0.5539005398750305,
            0.4446620047092438,
            -0.6139371395111084,
            -0.0760912224650383,
            0.47250989079475403,
            0.13905490934848785,
            -0.15110404789447784,
            0.2196819931268692,
            -0.015115287154912949,
            -0.0876191034913063,
            0.2190818190574646,
            0.15177731215953827,
            -0.11540143936872482,
            0.3143292963504791,
            -0.7955248951911926,
            -0.14175251126289368,
            -0.2351459413766861,
            -0.0020031873136758804,
            0.5531291961669922,
            0.19006197154521942,
            -0.44695913791656494,
            0.15765580534934998,
            -0.41821035742759705,
            -0.24712549149990082,
            -0.30841538310050964,
            1.0628894567489624,
            0.21696235239505768,
            -0.5680181384086609,
            0.14360393583774567,
            0.029083430767059326,
            0.3504600524902344,
            -0.2073742300271988,
            -0.07237754017114639,
            -0.4631251394748688,
            -0.01993762142956257,
            0.31713590025901794,
            0.19752036035060883,
            -0.45867791771888733,
            0.7844870090484619,
            -0.2899613082408905,
            -0.3508775234222412,
            0.11184930056333542,
            0.08467257022857666,
            0.06063457950949669,
            0.12691526114940643,
            -0.6400924324989319,
            0.15319986641407013,
            0.1950296014547348,
            -0.1831916719675064,
            -0.2643173336982727,
            -0.25775769352912903,
            -0.0383862741291523,
            0.3277539312839508,
            0.27097707986831665,
            -0.09319432824850082,
            0.17078693211078644,
            -0.16352562606334686,
            0.13986675441265106,
            -0.2126695066690445,
            -0.2646469473838806,
            0.17556767165660858,
            0.17156876623630524,
            0.06933357566595078,
            0.36875081062316895,
            -0.15373463928699493,
            -0.08859852701425552,
            -0.35353633761405945,
            -0.12193799763917923,
            -0.8119221329689026,
            -0.14899206161499023,
            0.13862772285938263,
            0.90940922498703,
            0.5533017516136169,
            0.46518024802207947,
            -0.16452465951442719,
            -0.08150187134742737,
            0.06050856038928032,
            0.004516924265772104,
            -0.07525651156902313,
            -0.36950698494911194,
            0.13500910997390747,
            0.5689918398857117,
            -0.13984568417072296,
            0.13541090488433838,
            -0.1710337996482849,
            0.5049394965171814,
            0.31605851650238037,
            -0.11508357524871826,
            0.25648927688598633,
            0.22325031459331512,
            0.0012158304452896118,
            0.6063514351844788,
            -0.41860270500183105,
            -0.215798020362854,
            0.0802639052271843,
            0.3938862979412079,
            0.41135427355766296,
            -0.3787707984447479,
            -0.08611714094877243,
            -0.08995003253221512,
            -0.14258436858654022,
            -0.328289270401001,
            -0.15199796855449677,
            0.291996568441391,
            0.3480320870876312,
            -0.12029280513525009,
            -0.29980534315109253,
            -0.15381667017936707,
            0.01715751923620701,
            0.418067067861557,
            0.10767596960067749,
            -0.49369239807128906,
            -0.24448750913143158,
            -0.1285122185945511,
            0.1464521884918213,
            0.06308989971876144,
            0.27997395396232605,
            -0.07993294298648834,
            -0.3860047161579132,
            0.26958078145980835,
            -0.041770875453948975,
            1.2096740007400513,
            -0.3259912431240082,
            0.03931817784905434,
            -0.03341643512248993,
            -0.4666934907436371,
            -0.015846841037273407,
            -0.5081338882446289,
            0.0096580283716321,
            0.02544138766825199,
            -0.09315574169158936,
            0.1747598499059677,
            0.36882948875427246,
            -0.06870802491903305,
            0.6053507328033447,
            -0.2759757936000824,
            0.15961496531963348,
            0.8063604235649109,
            -0.15020887553691864,
            -0.15171681344509125,
            -0.060200419276952744,
            -0.4110613167285919,
            -0.5835322737693787,
            -0.09726080298423767,
            -0.2392592579126358,
            -0.3616079092025757,
            0.027558647096157074,
            0.05291641876101494,
            0.12349791079759598,
            -0.007836289703845978,
            0.39525559544563293,
            -0.007334516849368811,
            0.2399410605430603,
            -0.4273543357849121,
            0.0991259291768074,
            -0.4819057881832123,
            0.3256849944591522,
            0.3032423257827759,
            -0.36083295941352844,
            -0.07435029000043869,
            0.2121112197637558,
            -0.364762544631958,
            -0.1596834510564804,
            0.04949704930186272,
            -0.16109593212604523,
            0.5034934878349304,
            0.10951238125562668,
            0.2869861423969269,
            0.13778208196163177,
            0.07069063931703568,
            -0.09771542996168137,
            -0.44196006655693054,
            0.5653741955757141,
            0.05989822372794151,
            -0.04989922046661377,
            -0.014927036128938198,
            -0.02302585542201996,
            0.17904798686504364,
            -0.002676159143447876,
            0.3416226804256439,
            -0.3578616678714752,
            -0.2932840585708618,
            0.2818126976490021,
            0.019605768844485283,
            -0.37913379073143005,
            -0.17880195379257202,
            -0.44554567337036133,
            -0.4738466441631317,
            0.28100961446762085,
            -0.1904536932706833,
            -0.03373843804001808,
            -0.2823610007762909,
            -0.19747000932693481,
            0.2464223951101303,
            0.22571444511413574,
            -0.05425698682665825,
            -0.16406866908073425,
            0.3493328392505646,
            -0.019189564511179924,
            0.1714441031217575,
            0.05705219507217407,
            0.5947189927101135,
            0.4346608817577362,
            0.676112711429596,
            -0.5242040753364563,
            0.3332209587097168,
            0.25352028012275696,
            0.027646541595458984,
            0.36309531331062317,
            -0.191823348402977,
            -0.011616709642112255,
            0.2157600373029709,
            0.34172940254211426,
            0.3011607527732849,
            -0.09793389588594437,
            -0.21880114078521729,
            0.5951963067054749,
            0.2308332920074463,
            -0.13228900730609894,
            -0.6290040612220764,
            -0.08339443057775497,
            0.1325439065694809,
            -0.6515927314758301,
            0.20590782165527344,
            -0.8780518174171448,
            -0.7029945254325867,
            0.13595467805862427,
            0.1822308450937271,
            -0.2715843915939331,
            -0.3809267580509186,
            -0.15282316505908966,
            0.22329704463481903,
            -0.22305679321289062,
            -0.012069642543792725,
            0.2796964943408966,
            -0.09808734059333801,
            0.20639513432979584,
            -0.07919856160879135,
            -0.2864263653755188,
            -0.14806243777275085,
            -0.045156244188547134,
            0.5580117106437683,
            0.22284358739852905,
            -0.5415909886360168,
            -0.21465997397899628,
            0.11937487125396729,
            -0.20431263744831085,
            -0.2403395175933838,
            0.07580457627773285,
            0.14617057144641876,
            -0.13944444060325623,
            0.24228675663471222,
            0.4678296148777008,
            -0.031120838597416878,
            -0.12779338657855988,
            0.08634798973798752,
            -0.04670761153101921,
            0.06502512842416763,
            0.07903987914323807,
            0.3355945348739624,
            -0.06577946990728378,
            0.07166757434606552,
            -0.1437894105911255,
            -0.5630078911781311,
            -0.13233913481235504,
            0.01655399054288864,
            0.3199481964111328,
            0.14370183646678925,
            0.11952924728393555,
            0.5970006585121155,
            -0.07086852192878723,
            0.10095593333244324,
            -0.7246183753013611,
            0.6260027289390564,
            -0.4862600564956665,
            -18.213258743286133,
            0.38144493103027344,
            0.08877747505903244,
            0.3688160479068756,
            0.20332185924053192,
            -0.4959397614002228,
            0.4932158887386322,
            -0.2113923579454422,
            -0.1950404793024063,
            0.3772925138473511,
            0.3376901149749756,
            0.028192894533276558,
            -0.597175657749176,
            0.10751038044691086,
            -0.38332363963127136,
            0.061080824583768845,
            0.2934887707233429,
            -0.16140936315059662,
            -0.030300596728920937,
            -0.11393174529075623,
            -0.4879361093044281,
            -0.08312537521123886,
            0.5829288363456726,
            -0.017795657739043236,
            0.17447303235530853,
            0.19649899005889893,
            0.26811954379081726,
            -0.18477855622768402,
            0.026489676907658577,
            -0.08490554243326187,
            0.04047516733407974,
            -0.05758599564433098,
            0.1733301877975464,
            0.30296510457992554,
            0.12135863304138184,
            -0.5401827692985535,
            0.01981624960899353,
            0.10279199481010437,
            0.5150095820426941,
            -0.21353882551193237,
            0.536064624786377,
            0.3912695348262787,
            0.6470407843589783,
            -0.14603863656520844,
            -0.17455945909023285,
            0.26098909974098206,
            -0.46810880303382874,
            -0.4509357213973999,
            0.6088793873786926,
            -0.09780841320753098,
            0.24819111824035645,
            0.2163211554288864,
            -0.3753402531147003,
            0.6355602741241455,
            -0.3911609649658203,
            -0.05401340499520302,
            -0.16659629344940186,
            -0.13565801084041595,
            0.501842200756073,
            0.1643461138010025,
            -0.21625493466854095,
            -0.6514524221420288,
            0.8899388313293457,
            0.26289352774620056,
            -0.25896701216697693,
            -0.3272574245929718,
            0.15999677777290344,
            -0.26547718048095703,
            -0.3032608926296234,
            -0.25007131695747375,
            -0.03964695334434509,
            0.1334560066461563,
            -0.17761678993701935,
            -0.004811423365026712,
            -0.08859457820653915,
            -0.13191309571266174,
            -0.4322088062763214,
            -0.6202206015586853,
            -0.14941012859344482,
            0.5533108711242676,
            -0.9611896872520447,
            0.14862070977687836,
            0.358111172914505,
            -0.2760471999645233,
            -0.15035228431224823,
            0.5983766913414001,
            -0.09283676743507385,
            0.40859857201576233,
            0.03840084746479988,
            -0.0427594929933548,
            0.23755036294460297,
            0.552716076374054,
            0.25461438298225403,
            0.08937105536460876,
            0.5074090361595154,
            -0.016884038224816322,
            -0.2121085524559021,
            0.21483175456523895,
            -0.3174271285533905,
            -0.5140398144721985,
            0.06363151222467422,
            0.014451566152274609,
            -0.4032210409641266,
            -0.0754266306757927,
            -0.2747887670993805,
            -0.05837796628475189,
            0.7825634479522705,
            0.4075222909450531,
            -0.7825568318367004,
            -0.35135790705680847,
            0.2962072193622589,
            -0.2863955795764923,
            -0.13005737960338593,
            0.7307493686676025,
            0.3552493751049042,
            -0.19790320098400116,
            -0.8183410167694092,
            -0.17674492299556732,
            0.24666698276996613,
            -0.01461823284626007,
            0.2410256713628769,
            -0.17540700733661652,
            0.18241678178310394,
            0.08976519852876663,
            -0.08760727196931839,
            0.012153185904026031,
            -0.2104892134666443,
            -0.7453539371490479,
            -0.06952495127916336,
            -0.28295353055000305,
            0.6779361367225647,
            -0.5319180488586426,
            -0.19127275049686432,
            -0.07256310433149338,
            0.2968808710575104,
            0.2115486115217209,
            0.26703646779060364,
            0.385223388671875,
            0.31249818205833435,
            -0.11475372314453125,
            -0.12362142652273178,
            -0.025776103138923645,
            0.19199372828006744,
            -0.27560412883758545,
            -0.027614548802375793,
            0.17952845990657806,
            0.30890682339668274,
            -0.4669407308101654,
            -1.1229356527328491,
            -0.14094625413417816,
            -0.7237748503684998,
            -0.33700716495513916,
            -0.29603925347328186,
            -0.20345592498779297,
            0.11142813414335251,
            0.08747435361146927,
            0.14150665700435638,
            -0.7253284454345703,
            0.22486639022827148,
            0.4361128509044647,
            0.22853289544582367,
            0.08715341240167618,
            0.2346210479736328,
            -0.03457959368824959,
            -0.17921000719070435,
            -0.6874427199363708,
            0.16873355209827423,
            -0.18384100496768951,
            0.23986661434173584,
            0.28883546590805054,
            0.13879145681858063,
            -0.15344975888729095,
            0.316563218832016,
            -0.25333499908447266,
            0.1651841402053833,
            -0.18934951722621918,
            -0.004195801913738251,
            0.041273608803749084,
            -0.14218632876873016,
            -0.01217249408364296,
            0.23939736187458038,
            -0.3173660933971405,
            -0.4909832775592804,
            -0.4912407696247101,
            0.08538653701543808,
            -0.28222790360450745,
            -0.15587706863880157,
            0.10141023248434067,
            0.3789379894733429,
            -0.11405836790800095,
            0.751940906047821,
            0.3117077648639679,
            -0.1643051952123642,
            -0.34755292534828186,
            -0.11532503366470337,
            0.2710844576358795,
            0.5446938872337341,
            -0.6947710514068604,
            0.32719090580940247,
            -0.26343023777008057,
            0.42235779762268066,
            0.5053179264068604,
            0.5381287336349487,
            -0.06117519736289978,
            0.21823382377624512,
            -0.2707849144935608,
            0.2575806677341461,
            0.3865841329097748,
            -0.314393013715744,
            0.34935781359672546,
            0.12102178484201431
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source":{
    "includes":[
      "title"
    ]
  }
}
```

It's worth filing a bug report.

Comment: The bug seems fixed, but now if you prettify you get a parse error (that's why i'm here) :D Anyway this question made me find a solution!

Comment: Great! Glad you found a solution.